# Why does my Spring Boot native image build take so long on macOS?

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a sample application (https://github.com/jwcarman/spring-native-demo) that I am using to demonstrate how to build a native image. When I build my image on Ubuntu, it takes about four minutes total. However, when I try to build it on macOS, it takes prohibitively long (I waited about an hour before I killed it).

I have allocated 5 CPUs, 32 GB RAM, 2 GB Swap, and 200 GB Virtual Disk limit to Docker Desktop. My machine is an M1 Max MacBook Pro, so I would expect it to build rather quickly (my Ubuntu box is rather old). The command I'm using to run the build is:

`mvn spring-boot:build-image -Pnative`

Here are the Java/Maven versions I'm using (output of `mvn -version`):

```
Apache Maven 3.8.7 (b89d5959fcde851dcb1c8946a785a163f14e1e29)
Maven home: /Users/jcarman/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.7-bin/678cc9d4/apache-maven-3.8.7
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "13.2.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented on the Spring Boot wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-GraalVM#building-container-images), Cloud Native buildpacks, which is what it used by `mvn spring-boot:build-image`, do not yet support M1 Macs:

> Building Container Images
>
> Paketo Buildpacks do not yet have [official support for building images for ARM](https://github.com/buildpacks/lifecycle/issues/435). But there are [alternative builders available](https://github.com/dashaun/paketo-arm64) which support building on ARM.

As described in the [README of the alternative build](https://github.com/dashaun/paketo-arm64/tree/2b1a25bdc9bdece62b55a89df7a31840da7dfdb5), you can use it by replacing

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

with this:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <builder>dashaun/builder:tiny</builder>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you, Andy Wilkinson! 

I was following the directions here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html

and didn't see any mention of these issues. I updated my pom.xml file accordingly (activating a profile automatically on `aarch64`) and now everything is building! I appreciate your quick reply.